# javascript objects sent from server does not have methods on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i am using socket.io v4 and i am trying to send object from server to the client side

the client side gets the object but it does not have any methods only the properties

i have tried using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse still did not work

Comment: You cant send javascript methods like that. When you serialize it only sends the properties

Comment: Please, share your code so that we can help you. You can send functions between server and client side

Comment: because JSON does not have functions.

Comment: It sounds like you should have a class on the clientside, you send the JSON down and you instantiate the class with that data.

Comment: so is it not possible to send the whole object at all? what im tring to send is an object made with constructor

Comment: You can't do that. JSON is a language-agnostic format, so it doesn't make sense to have functions in it -- what language would they be in?